# L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'

Tags: r

```
view(b)

data.class(b)

DF = data.frame(r=b)

data.matrix(DF)

str(DF)
> rt<- as.matrix(DF)

class(rt)

[1] "matrix"



str(rt)

 num [1:204, 1:2] 94.8 96.2 98.1 99.1 100 …

 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL

  ..$ : chr [1:2] "r.tf" "r.usd"



nrow(rt)

[1] 204
 ncol(rt)

[1] 2
 str(rt)

 num [1:204, 1:2] 94.8 96.2 98.1 99.1 100 …

 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2

  ..$ : NULL

  ..$ : chr [1:2] "r.tf" "r.usd"


> data.class(rt)

[1] "matrix"

> ts.plot(rt)

> acf(rt, lag=100)

> library(LongMemoryTS)

> VARFIMA.est(rt, approx = 100, rep= FALSE)

Error in optim(par = start2, fn = ll.VARFIMA, data = data[from[aa]:to[aa],
  L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'

Warning message:
In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : possible convergence problem: optim gave code = 1
```

I don't understand why my codes don't work. Can someone help?

Comment: I removed the python tag.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: L-BFGS-B is an optimisation method requiring high and low bounds. Meaning you can't provide only start parameters but also lower and higher bounds.

Comment: Do you have some missing values in your data (or Inf or other junk such as characters)?